# AdMob not displaying in fragment Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, admob

AdMob not displaying in fragment Activity, my code goes as below. but the same code works in normal activity. Not getting what is wrong in this code. please suggest

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_delete);

    adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

}

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        style="@style/button_style"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:text="@string/delete" />

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/advertisement"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="6693e1e6c1d543f4" >
        </com.google.ads.AdView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_startdate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/start_date" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_startdate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:hint="@string/dateFormat"
        android:inputType="date" />

    <requestFocus />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_enddate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/end_date" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_enddate"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:hint="@string/dateFormat"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:singleLine="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<!-- Required permission to check licensing. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainFragmentActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".extra.SearchManager" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DeleteRecords"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainFragmentActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the following into your Manifest file (Inside application). Also add and reference the Google Play services library project in your Eclipse workspace, if you haven't done it yet.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

[Here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/) is a full tutorial by Google.